# Looking for original French quote of Napoleon about a dead soldier's dog

Tags: citations

I am looking for the original French version and the source of the following quote of Napoleon about a dead solider's dog:

> "This soldier, I realized, must have had friends at home and in his
>   regiment; yet he lay there deserted by all except his dog. I had
>   looked on, unmoved, at battles which decided the future of nations.
>   Tearless, I had given orders which brought death to thousands.
>   Yet, here I was stirred, profoundly stirred, stirred to tears. And by
>   what? By the grief of one dog."

Any help appreciated.

@LPH thank you.
Original:

> Cet homme, me disais-je, a peut-être des amis ; il en a peut-être dans
>   le camp, dans sa compagnie, et il gît ici abandonné de tous excepté de
>   son chien ! Quelle leçon la nature nous donnait par l’intermédiaire
>   d’un animal ! Ce qu’est l’homme ! Et quel n’est pas le mystère de ses
>   impressions ! J’avais sans émotion ordonné des batailles qui devaient
>   décider du sort de l’armée ; j’avais vu d’un œil sec exécuter des
>   mouvements qui amenaient la perte d’un grand nombre d’entre nous ; et
>   ici je me sentais ému, j’étais remué par les cris et la douleur d’un
>   chien !

source:

Mémorial de Sainte-Hélène: Tome I - De juin 1815 à mars 1816
https://books.google.de/books?id=X_vwCQAAQBAJ

Comment: Hello, I did some search but couldn't find it, do you please have any link to the english quote? This may help, thanks.

Comment: @Ced i first saw it here: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/109399-this-soldier-i-realized-must-have-had-friends-at-home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [something](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/canine-corner/201803/the-dogs-napoleon-bonaparte) that might be exactly what you want but it's in English ; it is not possible to use it as a repost, though (Copyright SC Psychological Enterprises Ltd. May not be reprinted or reposted without permission). The account  is faithful to the rendering provided in the question, and ther is much additional information on the importance of dogs in Napoleon's life.

You might contact the [psychologist](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/experts/stanley-coren-phd-dsc-frsc) that posted this and obtain a source or the quote itself (contact field at the end of the page).

What follows could contain the original [quote](https://ecoleduchiotortega.com/comportement/napoleon-aime-chiens/);

A la bataille de Bassano (8 septembre 1796), il est fortement touché devant un chien qui ne peut se résoudre à quitter le cadavre de son maître et continuait à le lécher tout en faisant entendre ses cris de douleur: "C'était par un beau clair de lune et dans la solitude profonde de la nuit. Tout à coup, un chien sortant de dessous les vêtements d'un cadavre s'élança sur nous et retourna aussitôt à son gîte en poussant des cris douloureux. il léchait tout à tour le visage de son maître et se lançait de nouveau sur nous ; c'était tout à la fois demander du secours et chercher la vengeance. Soit disposition du moment, soit le lieu, l'heure, le temps, l'acte en lui-même, ou je ne sais quoi, toujours est-il vrai que jamais, sur aucun de mes champs de bataille, fait ne me causa une impression pareille. Je m'arrêtai involontairement à contempler ce spectacle. Cet homme, me disais-je, a peut-être des amis, il en a peut-être dans le camp, dans sa compagnie, et il gît ici, abandonné de tous, excepté de son chien ! Quelle leçon la nature nous donnait, par l'intermédiaire d'un animal".

---

Here is something else; it contains the other quote and there is the beginning of an indication to find the [source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Bassano). The quote is to be traced back to "discussions avec Las Cases à Sainte-Hélène".
Une anecdote est liée à cette bataille de la première campagne d'Italie.

Lors d’une de ses multiples discussions avec Las Cases à Sainte-Hélène, l’empereur lui relata un événement de la première campagne d’Italie qui l’avait marqué.

L’action se déroule à Bassano le 8 septembre 1796 où, alors général, il remporte une victoire décisive sur les Autrichiens du comte Wurmser qui lui abandonnèrent cinq drapeaux, trente-cinq pièces de canon attelées, autant de caissons, deux équipages de pont de trente-deux bateaux, également attelés, et plus de deux cents fourgons avec une partie des bagages de l'armée ennemie restèrent dans les mains des vainqueurs

Traversant le champ de bataille à la suite de cette affaire, il se déplace parmi les morts quand soudain… : 
Par un beau clair de lune et dans la solitude profonde de la nuit, un chien sortant tout à coup de dessous les vêtements d’un cadavre, s’élança sur nous et retourna presque aussitôt à son gîte, en poussant des cris douloureux ; il léchait tour à tour le visage de son maître, et se lançait de nouveau sur nous ; c’était tout à la fois demander du secours et rechercher la vengeance.Soit disposition du moment, soit du lieu, l’heure, le temps, l’acte en lui-même, ou je ne sais quoi, toujours est-il vrai que jamais rien, sur aucun de mes champs de bataille, ne me causa une impression pareille.Je m’arrêtais involontairement à contempler ce spectacle.Cet homme, me disais-je, a peut-être des amis ; il en a peut-être dans le camp, dans sa compagnie, et il gît ici abandonné de tous excepté de son chien !Quelle leçon la nature nous donnait par l’intermédiaire d’un animal !Ce qu’est l’homme ! Et quel n’est pas le mystère de ses impressions ! J’avais sans émotion ordonné des batailles qui devaient décider du sort de l’armée ; j’avais vu d’un œil sec exécuter des mouvements qui amenaient la perte d’un grand nombre d’entre nous ; et ici je me sentais ému, j’étais remué par les cris et la douleur d’un chien !Ce qu’il y a de bien certain, c’est qu’en ce moment j’eusse été plus traitable pour un ennemi suppliant ; je concevais mieux Achille rendant le corps d’Hector aux larmes de Priam.

---

It's quite possible the quote is in this [book](https://www.site-annonce.fr/las-cases-saint-helene).

Comment: ok, I sent him a message asking for the source. Let's see if he replies..

Comment: perfect, thank you so much! The source is Mémorial de Sainte-Hélène: Tome I - De juin 1815 à mars 1816, https://books.google.de/books?id=X_vwCQAAQBAJ

Comment: he did in fact reply! "This quote comes from "Mémorial de Sainte-Hélène" by the Comte de Las Cases (Emmanuelle) 1815."

Answer (score 2):

These links might help you as well:

- [Napoleon Series Archive 2015](http://www.napoleon-series.org/cgi-bin/forum/archive2015_config.pl?md=read;id=163236)
- [Moustache, le p'tit cabot de l'Empire](https://www.dialogus2.org/BON/moustacheleptitcabotdelempire.html)
- [Dictionnaire Anecdotes](https://www.scribd.com/document/63806618/Dictionnaire-Anecdotes)
- [Bataille de Bassano](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Bassano)
- [Forum Napoléon Ier - Débattre dans le silence des passions](https://forum.napoleon1er.net/viewtopic.php?t=38612&start=20)
- [La campagne de Russie](http://www.passion-histoire.net/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=30250&start=135)

Comment: bonjour, wow, thank you. I will take some time tomorrow to look at the links...